# purpose of nl_socket_set_cb() in libnl

Tags: c, linux

Recently, I'm studying `iw`'s source code trying to understand how `libnl` works.

I encountered the use of `nl_socket_set_cb()` at some point of `iw.c` for reasons I can't comprehend. There is no documentation on the web as well.

My first suspect would be to associate a callback function when there is data to be read from the nl socket but this is done in other part of the source code by associating a callback when calling `nl_recvmsgs()`.

Can anyone shed some light? Is `nl_socket_set_cb()` redundant ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use [nl_recvmsgs(sk, cb)](https://github.com/thom311/libnl/blob/master/lib/nl.c#L1023), you still need to use [nl_socket_set_cb(sk, cb)](https://github.com/thom311/libnl/blob/master/lib/socket.c#L614) if you plan on using the [NL_CB_MSG_OUT](https://github.com/thom311/libnl/blob/master/lib/nl.c#L310) callback. That callback is called in `nl_sendmsg()` before sending anything through the socket.

However if you instead use [nl_recvmsgs_default(sk)](https://github.com/thom311/libnl/blob/master/lib/nl.c#L1039), then `nl_socket_set_cb()` is handy since it stores callbacks within the `sk->s_cb` struct, which is passed to sending and receiving functions.

I think the real use of `nl_socket_set_sb()` is to re-use `nl_recvmsgs_default()` with the same socket, as it appears to remove any previously-set callbacks stored in the `sk` struct.

https://github.com/thom311/libnl/blob/master/lib/nl.c

https://github.com/thom311/libnl/blob/master/lib/socket.c

https://github.com/thom311/libnl/blob/master/include/netlink-private/types.h

https://github.com/thom311/libnl/blob/master/lib/handlers.c